# Angular with keycloak integration gives CORS error for password grant_type

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am trying to integrate keycloak with my angular web application with grant_type "PASSWORD" using my custom login form to get username and password.

I have added my client under realm settings in keycloak and enabled Standard, implicit, direct access grant and service accounts options.

Configured my Valid Redirect URL as : http://localhost:4200/*
Base URL : http://localhost:4200
And web origins with + ( tried with * as well)

Also, added user and updated password.

With postman/insomnia, I am able to consume keycloak rest API and get access, refresh and id tokens for grant_type "password"
URL: http://localhost:8080/realms/typing-office/protocol/openid-connect/token
Method: Post
Headers: Content_type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Form URL encoded as below:
grant_type: password
scope: openid
client_secret: MY_CLIENT_SECRET_RETRIEVED_FROM_KEYCLOAK
client_id: MY_CLIENT_ID
username: TEST_USER
password: TEST_PWD

It works fine with postman/insomnia. However, it fails while trying to integrate with angular.

Getting CORS error as shown below:
Preflight request is successful with 200 response as shown below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP5SQ.png)
Actual request fails with Referrer policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssxp8.png)

I tried with angular proxy as well however still it doesn't work. Any idea what could be an issue?
Key cloak server version: 17.0.1

Any working of angular integration with keycloak for "password" grant_type?

Comment: What method does the second request use (the one ending in `/connect/token`)? From what I can see based on the OPTIONS response, the server only allows you to use `POST` and `OPTIONS` (only these are present in the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header).

Comment: http://localhost:8080/realms/typing-office/protocol/openid-connect/token is for password grant_type login .. it will return access token, id and refresh tokens along with other param.. I am using POST for login as per keycloak REST API definition. Options is pre-flight request triggered internally by angular